# Can I use an iPad 3 as a wireless monitor?

Tags: wireless-networking, graphics-card, remote-desktop, vnc, processing

I need a high-resolution monitor for multi-monitoring applications, but I don't have much room for a big TV. I had the idea of buying an iPad3 (2048x1536!) instead and sending the screen of a Windows XP running on a local computer over wlan. Is it possible without affecting the use experience - that is - 100% smooth? I've done the calculations for a 108mbits wlan (13500000bytes/s):

```
13500000 bytes/s / (3 bytes/pixel * (2056*1536) pixels/screen) = 1.42 screens/s
```

So I got a 1.5 fps without compression. With PNG compression plus sending only different pixels I guess it would be possible to reach a good 30fps; but I'm not sure if a computer is able to take 30 screen shots + compare 30 images + compress 30 images all in a sec. Is it?

Comment: There are at least a few remote desktop apps for iPad, that seems like a much easier solution.

Comment: Yes but what I am trying to figure out is if they will be able to render a full windows screen at 30fps.

Answer (score 0):

The only way this could be used as a monitor is if an application is written custom tailored for such purpose. I haven't heard of one, so I think you're swimming uphill on this one.

In reality, if you're buying an iPAD 3 for a monitor, you're wasting your money.

iPAD 3: Starting at $499, $599, $699 (all USD), and it goes up from there: http://store.apple.com/us/browse/home/shop_ipad/family/ipad/select_ipad

Assuming you have the connectivity, you could purchase MORE THAN two monitors, with height adjustable stands, and many more options: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16824260062

Comment: In my case, I had an iPad 2 already and wanted to make extra use of the great little screen. Even if it's small, it's a great addition when coding or editing photos.

Comment: If you have an iPad 2, then why did you say iPad 3 in the title? Also, developing a game on a smaller screen is working against yourself, unless you are planning to release for that platform. In that case, using at as a monitor is not exactly the ideal environment, as that will not be how most people would be using the device. You would want to re-create the typical setup.

Comment: BloodyIron he is not the OP.

Comment: Was just explaining that while buying iPad with the **sole** purpose of using it as an extra monitor would indeed be silly, I too think it's a great idea if you happen to have an iPad anyway :-)

Comment: @dokkat Lol whoops, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

"Without affecting user experience" and "100% smooth" - well, it depends on what you're displaying. Is it 100 fps gaming, HD video or...?

I use [AirDisplay](http://avatron.com/apps/air-display), which does an OK job.

Comment: I need at least 30fps full screen updates. I'll be specifially programming a game. AirDisplay seems great, I'll look that.

Comment: LCD monitors, since they first were released for desktops, have all performed at least at 60hz, this means they draw at least 60 fimtes a second, hence they can handle up to 60fps. If you need more, you will need to get a 120hz monitor, or higher, and make sure it's properly configured. Where did you get the notion "30fps" was impossible on modern monitors? How bizzare!

Comment: @BloodyIron - I think Dokkat wasn't doubting that a monitor can run 30fps, but was doubting that there's something that can process the data and send it to an iPad for display that fast.

Comment: Again, it depends. Lots of things will affect your performance. Graphics are drawn differently on the screen, depending on whet ever it's a standard Windows program or a game, if you're using DirectX or something else. It's about what is best suited for whatever algorithm AirDisplay (or your product of choice) uses to send screen updates across. I highly doubt that AirDisplay (or any other program like it) actually takes 30 screenshots a second, compresses them and sends them across. Try it and see how it performs - it's not terribly expensive :-)

Comment: It is not, but I have to buy the iPad before and I will only do it if it certainly can 'run' the XP.

Comment: That's going to be tough then. Guess you have to see if you can borrow an iPad from i friend, spend the money for AirDisplay on his/her iPad and test. If it doesn't work, it only cost you the price of AD. On the downside, if it _does_ work well enough, you'll have to buy AirDisplay on your own iTunes account again.

Answer (score 0):

I use [iDisplay](http://www.getidisplay.com/) and it works.  Its cheaper than AirDisplay (mentioned in another answer) but it works fine, but there is lag, but Im only running a .11g network.